Single customer multiple stripe subscription
I'm developing a small Saas.
the business logic is like this:

Each user can have multiple cards
There are three types of "cards" => Free ($0), Basic ($10), Pro($20), which are stored as stripe products, paid monthly/yearly
User can have one type of plan attached to each card

Right now I can't figure it out.
I'm using stripe pricing table (it's an MVP, nothing fancy)
I cannot understand how can I set the id card with subscription and how to avoid that the stripe checkout screen says that user is already registered.

Edit
The pricing table is created from here
I've created two products (Basic & Pro).
I've tried with regular products (one shot sell) and Per-seat products (which seems to be close to my case)
What I want is making the customer able to have a situation like this: [Card is an instance on my DB, Basic/Pro are Stripe products in the Pricing table]

Card A => Basic Stripe plan.
Card B => Basic Stripe plan.
Card C => Pro Stripe plan.
Card D => Basic Stripe plan.

... and so on.

Any tips?!
Thanks

Your flow isn't very clear (at least to me).  The Pricing table (https://docs.stripe.com/no-code/pricing-table) allows your customers to select from multiple products on the same billing interval.  It should not matter if customers already have an existing subscription.
How are you creating your Pricing Table?  What options are you selecting?  The ID when you say you don't understand how you can set the id card, isn't that the Product ID?  Can you clarify all your terms with explicit references to Stripe objects?  It'll help others (myself included) help you.

Sorry if i was not clear.
the pricing table is created from here (https://dashboard.stripe.com/pricing-tables)
I've created two products (Basic & Pro).
I've tryied with regular products (one shot sell) and Per-seat products (wich seems to be close to my case)
What I want is making the customer able to have a situation like this:
[Card is an instance on my DB, Basic/Pro are Stripe products in the Pricing table]

Card A => Basic Stripe plan.
Card B => Basic Stripe plan.
Card C => Pro Stripe plan.
Card D => Basic Stripe plan.
... and so on.


I recommend you update your post with these details.  It's hard to review the whole ask, going back and forth between comments and the original post.
